# VBA Schema Table Doesnt Include Newly Added Worksheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I have a VBA Code that connects to the workbook itself to execute SQL queries. The macro adds Worksheets during runtime.

E.g. ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "TempSheet"

After adding this worksheet, the VBA Macro adds data on the TempSheet.

I will be executing SQL query against the newly added worksheet using this code:

```
Dbase = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Connection_string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & Dbase & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open Connection_string

SQL_String = "SELECT * FROM [TempSheet$A1:U182]"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open SQL_String, cn
```

On the line where it executes the query at rs.Open, I get an error saying

```
The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'TempSheet$A1:U182'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'TempSheet$A1:U182' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.
```

I am very sure that the Worksheet name matches but still it seems that VBA ADO cannot find the newly added worksheet on the workbook.

Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: Did you save the file after adding the sheet and the data?

Comment: Hi Tim - no i don't. What i found weird is for other machine/laptop, using the same file and line of codes works, but for others dont.